# How to make a ajax xml request with https

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to execute SOAP with AJAX. I'm sending the same XML and URL I use with SOAPUI. As response I get:

> net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

```js
var dataXml =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:req=\"htpp://request.xsd\">" +
    "<soapenv:Header/>" +
    "<soapenv:Body>" +
    /*data*/ 
    "</soapenv:Body>" +
    "</soapenv:Envelope>";

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://url:8090/route',
    data: dataXml, 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    headers: {
        SOAPAction: '/SOAPActionFromSoapUI'
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        alert("ok");
    },
    error : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("error");
    } 
});
```

In SOAPUI, I watch:

```
POST https://url:8090/route HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "/SOAPActionFromSoapUI"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: url:8090
Content-Length: 673
```

How can I get a secure connection?

Comment: HTTPS connections use port 443 by default. Specifying a port in the URL may cause issues. Try removing `:8090`

Comment: if i remove the port, i get a net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Are you sure your server supports SSL?

Comment: the server I trying to access or the one where I have the js file?

Comment: The one you're calling in the AJAX request

Comment: thanks! thats my problem!